# Filtered dataset not appearing in listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I need assistance with a VBA coded workbook that is supposed to display a range of filtered data into a listbox on a userform that appears when clicking an ActiveX control button.

I have a worksheet with data ranging from A9 to BR15000. The worksheet has 2 buttons on it, button A and button B. Button A automatically filters the worksheet based on my needs. Button B is then supposed to open a userform with a list box that autopopulates and displays the filtered data.

The issue is that it begins to list the data until it comes upon a row that has been hidden by the filter. Once this occurs, the VBA code stops and displays only part of the data set. It does not display all the rows that are visible. Below is the code I'm using to populate the listbox when the userform opens. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Clear the ListBox
    ListBox1.Clear
    
    ' Define the range to populate listbox
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Janes Tab") ' Modify the sheet name as needed
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range("A8:BR15000") ' Modify the range as needed
    
    ' Get the last visible row in the filtered range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    ' Get the filtered range (excluding headers and beyond the last visible row)
    Dim filteredRange As Range
    Set filteredRange = rng.Resize(lastRow - rng.row + 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ' Populate the ListBox with filtered records
    Dim row As Range
    Dim column As Range
    
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Long
    rowCount = filteredRange.Rows.Count
    
    ' Determine the count of visible columns
    Dim visibleColumnCount As Long
    visibleColumnCount = 0
    
    Dim columnIndex As Long
    For columnIndex = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        If rng.Columns(columnIndex).Hidden = False Then
            visibleColumnCount = visibleColumnCount + 1
        End If
    Next columnIndex
    
    Debug.Print "RowCount: " & rowCount
    Debug.Print "VisibleColumnCount: " & visibleColumnCount
    
    Dim rowData() As Variant ' Array to store values of each row
    ReDim rowData(1 To rowCount, 1 To visibleColumnCount) ' Resize the array
    
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim visibleColumnIndex As Long
    
    For rowIndex = 1 To rowCount
        visibleColumnIndex = 1 ' Reset the index for each row
        For columnIndex = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If rng.Columns(columnIndex).Hidden = False Then
                rowData(rowIndex, visibleColumnIndex) = filteredRange.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value
                visibleColumnIndex = visibleColumnIndex + 1
            End If
        Next columnIndex
    Next rowIndex
    
    ListBox1.List = rowData ' Assign the array as the ListBox rows
    
    ' Adjust column widths based on data width
    ListBox1.columnWidths = "20;50;40;20;20;450;50;40;20;20;20;50;40;20;20" ' Adjust the width value as needed for each visible column
    
    ' Clear the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`filteredRange` is going to be split into an awful lot of areas. Not only will it split the range into row blocks, but each row block will be split into column blocks since you have hidden columns. Run the following:

```
Debug.Print filteredRange.Address
Debug.Print filteredRange.Areas.Count
```

Therefore,

```
rowCount = filteredRange.Rows.Count
```

is equivalent to

```
rowCount = filteredRange.Areas(1).Rows.Count
```

As a quick fix try working only with `rng`:

```
    ' changed here
    For rowIndex = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        If Not rng.Rows(rowIndex).EntireRow.Hidden Then
            visibleColumnIndex = 1 ' Reset the index for each row
            For columnIndex = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
                If rng.Columns(columnIndex).Hidden = False Then
                    ' changed here
                    rowData(rowIndex, visibleColumnIndex) = rng.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value
                    visibleColumnIndex = visibleColumnIndex + 1
                End If
            Next columnIndex
        End If
    Next rowIndex
```

**Aside:** The more your code interacts with the excel application, the slower it is. It is much more efficient if you can read your data into an array in memory (something like `data = rng.Value`) and then process your `data`.

Try the following (**not tested**):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'In case there're lots of formulas
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Janes Tab")
        
    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = getVisibleData(rng:=ws.Range("A9:BR15000"), includeFirstRow:=True)
        ListBox1.columnWidths = "20;50;40;20;20;450;50;40;20;20;20;50;40;20;20"
    End With
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Private Function getVisibleData(rng As Range, Optional includeFirstRow As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        With .UsedRange
            If includeFirstRow Then
                getVisibleData = .Value
            Else
                getVisibleData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Value
            End If
        End With
        .Delete
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

The idea of the function is to add a dummy sheet (which will be deleted later) and simply copy and paste your range. We should make excel do the heavy lifting whenever possible: It's usually far more efficient than our VBA code. You can also have a premanent hidden dummy sheet to save adding and deleting a temporary sheet.